# What’s the difference between “what you had to say” and “what you said”?

Tags: difference, verbs

What’s the difference between

“I really loved what you had to say”

“I really loved what you said”

Comment: "What you had to say" implies some kind of prepared speech rather than a casual remark.

Comment: ... and further, ' "What you had to say" [suggests] some kind of prepared speech' strongly suggests a formal setting. At the very least, it shows the delivery of a carefully considered, heartfelt opinion – even _if_ the opportunity was merely providential. // "I really loved what you said” connotes a less deep response, possibly a one-off compliment for a one-off statement.